# Patterns in the first digit of $2^n$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

Computing the last digits of the powers of $n$ can be done efficiently with modular exponents. However computing the first digits of the powers of $n$ efficiently is not trivial for base 10.

And so one might naturally begin looking for patterns in the powers of $n$. We generate the first digit of $2^n$ up to a large $n$, then identify sequences which seemed to repeat often & highlight them. After doing so, the number of columns is adjusted to find a pattern. Using a columns of 10 digits, and highlighting some particular sequences the following pattern emerges: ([link for for more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Hk4.png)):

[image: Pattern for first digit of 2^n]

What is the pattern?

Comment: Upto some point, the pattern will continue , but because of the irrationality of $\log_{10}(2)$ , this will not continue forever.

Comment: For example , we cannot compute the first digits of Graham's number , although it is just a power of $3$. For an analogue number with base $2$ , we would be in a similar hopeless situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each first digit of a power of 2, there are only one or two possible first digits of the next power of 2 (for instance: doubling a number with first digit 3 can only give a number with first digit 6 or 7; doubling a number with first digit 7 can only give a number with first digit 1). Thus the first digits can only appear in the cycles 1>2>5>1; 1>3>6>1; 1>3>7>1; 1>2>4>9>1; 1>2>4>8>1. In general, the sequence will change course from one of these to any other at a first digit of 1, but unpredictably, in the long run, because as the comments point out, $\log_{10}2$ is irrational. The reason why columns of 10 creates a considerable degree of regularity is just that $2^{10} \approx 10^3$.

Comment: (+1) In fact, using better approximations, we can find (more complicated) patterns that hold even longer , but eventually they will break down.